# parallel assign in PHP

Tags: php, php-7.4

just saw the new feature in PHP called **unpacking variable** it goes like 
`$arr = ["sth", "another thing", ...$another_array, "other"]`
and it makes me curious that if I can use splat operator (or any other way, result matters) like this

```
list($headers, ...$rows) = explode("\n", $csv_data);
```

so im going to have two variables, `String $headers` that contains my csv headers and `Array $rows` that has my rows in it, how can i achive that ?

Answer (score 1):

The `...` operator first introduced in `PHP 5.6` as **argument unpacking** operator

In `PHP 7.4` however they introduce a new usage of that operator and call it **the spread operator** in which an array prefixed by `...` will be expanded in places during array definition.

Now when you use the splat operator `...` this way

```
list($headers, ...$rows) = explode("\n", $csv_data);
```

That means you want to extract the values in `$rows` array to represent values in your `$csv_data` array

So if `$rows` contains

```
$rows = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'];
```

Is roughly equivalent to

```
list($headers, $row1, $row2, $row3) = explode("\n", $csv_data);
```

But that's not possible!

> Fatal error: Spread operator is not supported in assignments

What you need is [str_getcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to parse your CSV data into an array

**Usage**

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'));
```

Comment: It is not possible, despite some misleading articles suggesting otherwise.

Bad info also here: https://dev.to/rrsai/destructuring-in-php-3ad1#what-about-spreading-values

Comment: Confirmed @Vladan, that article is misleading and although it looks he has updated it, he hasn't updated it with correct information. It looks like `str_getcsv` will probably be the way to go.